# open connection to mysql for multiple inserts

Tags: mysql, bash, mariadb

I have file which is constantly growing, because some process is writing to it. My goal is to start another process which will monitor changes in this file, make some sed/awk/bash preprocessing and then insert result to database. This can be achieved by following command:

```
#!/bin/bash

tail -f -n +1 growing_file | while read a; do
  query=$(echo "$a" | awk '{print "use log; INSERT INTO log (message) VALUES(\"" $4 "\");"}';)
  echo "$query"
  mysql -u root -pSecretPassword -h dbs-host -e "$query"
done
```

But it has a drawback that for each insert I need to make separate connection, authenticate, select database and finally make insert. This also returns errors after after few seconds of run:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'dbs-host'
>   (111 "Connection refused")

What would like to achieve is to open connection to database and then reuse this opened connection for inserts. I've tried `coproc` command but I'm unable to achieve my goal.

PS: solutions in other languages than bash are also welcomed (python, node.js, ...)

Comment: Does that script get "behind"?  Is the machine overloaded?  If 'no' to both, then "If it ain't broke, don't fix it."

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler way to write your code:

```
tail -f -n +1 growing_file | 
awk '{ print "INSERT INTO log SET message = '"'"'\"${4}\"'"'"';" }' |
mysql -u root -pSecretPassword -h dbs-host log
```

P.S. I recommend you put your username, password and perhaps host into an options file instead of putting them on the command-line.

```
tail -f -n +1 growing_file | 
awk '{ print "INSERT INTO log SET message = '"'"'\"${4}\"'"'"';" }' |
mysql --defaults-file=log.cnf log
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is a [connection pool mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool). In a connection pool, you open a connection once, then reuse it as much as you need, instead of creating new database connections, and it performs much faster.

I am not sure which connection pools libraries are available for bash. In Java I use [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP), but there are other options out there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice script for Bash to [**How to Keep a MySQL Connection Open in Bash**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463106/how-to-keep-a-mysql-connection-open-in-bash) , but are you sure to get the filesize so often. There is no sleep in your script.

You also can write a MySQL / MariaDb User Function in C. this is much better and faster and you can start it from the MySQL scheduler.